# Building an egg of my python project

Tags: python, egg, scrapyd

Can somebody please guide me with step-by-step procedure on how to eggfy my existing python project? The documentation is keep mentioning something about setup.py within a package but I cannot find it in my project...

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming scrapy daemon run on localhost, it should be as simple as:

```
cd /root/of/scrapy/project/where/scrapy.cfg/is
scrapy deploy
```

otherwise, insert another entry in scrapy.cfg file, for example:

```
[deploy:scrapyd2]
url = http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/
username = john
password = secret
```

for more info see [scrapyd documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/scrapyd.html)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply - so I don't need to create .egg file to run my scrapy project on scraped? say if my scrapy project is stored under `/Users/jd/Desktop/grimes2`, I just have to type `cd /Users/jd/Desktop/grimes2/is` and then execute `scrapy deploy` on terminal? thank you,

Answer (score 11):

You can use [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to achieve that. In two steps, you just need to:

#### Create the setup.py script

This file calls the setuptools API that takes care of building your package. A very simple `setup.py` would look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='A short description',
    long_description='I would just open("README.md").read() here',
    author='Author of the Project',
    author_email='author@company.com',
    url='https://github.com/user/proj',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['*tests*']),
)
```

#### Generate the .egg file

That's definitely the easier part. You just have to call

```
$ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

Just look at the `dist` directory created and you'll find the `.egg` file.

I'd suggest you to take a look in a very good tutorial about setuptools: http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the question was specific to scrapyd. Does it make sense to keep this answer here?